# How to access a website running in a container when you´re using network_mode: host

Tags: docker, docker-network, docker-desktop

I have a very tricky topic because I need to access a private DB in AWS. In order to connect to this DB, first I need to create a bridge like this:

`ssh -L 127.0.0.1:LOCAL_PORT:DB_URL:PORT -N -J ACCOUNT@EMAIL.DOMAIN -i ~/KEY_LOCATION/KEY_NAME.pem PC_USER@PC_ADDRESS`

Via `127.0.0.1:LOCAL_PORT:DB_URL` I can connect to the DB in my Java app. Let´s say the port is 9991 for this case.

My docker files more or less look this:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  api:
    image: fanmixco/example:v0.01
    build:
      context: .
    network_mode: host
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:9991/MY_DB
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:11
RUN mkdir /home/app/
WORKDIR /home/app/
RUN mkdir logs
COPY ./target/MY_JAVA_APP.jar .

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "MY_JAVA_APP.jar"]
```

The image runs properly. However, if I try:

- using localhost:8080/MY_APP fails
- using 127.0.0.1/MY_APP fails
- getting the container's IP and use it later fails
- using host.docker.internal/MY_APP fails

I´m wondering how I can test my app. I know it´s running because I get a successful message in the console and the new data was added to the DB, but I don´t know how I can test it or access it. Any idea of the proper way to do it? Thanks.

P.S.:

1. I´m running my Images in Docker Desktop for Windows.
2. I have another case using tomcat 9 and running `CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]` and I know it's working because I get this message in the console:

> INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [9905] milliseconds

But I cannot access it again.

Comment: Sorry, I’m not at a computer right now to try. But what does `docker-compose ps` output?

Comment: `docker-compose ps` typically tells you which host port is mapped to any particular container port. I’m just not sure how it behaves with `network_mode` set to `host`.

Comment: Hi @ZhaoLim, *"If you use the host network mode for a container, that container’s network stack is not isolated from the Docker host (the container shares the host’s networking namespace), and the container does not get its own IP-address allocated. For instance, if you run a container which binds to port 80 and you use host networking, the container’s application is available on port 80 on the host’s IP address."* More info: https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what the issue is based on the above information since I cannot replicate the system on my own machine.

However, these are some places to look:

- you might be running into an issue similar to this: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1031 because of the networking magic you are doing with `ssh` and AWS DB
- you should try specifying either a build/`Dockerfile` or an image, and avoid specifying both

  ```
    version: '3.4'
    services:
      api:
        image: fanmixco/example:v0.01 # choose using an image
        build:                        # or building from a Dockerfile
          context: .                  # but not both
        network_mode: host
        environment:
          - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:9991/MY_DB
  ```

Hope that helps  and good luck

Answer (score -1):

I guess you need to bind the port of your container.

Try to add the 'port' property to your docker-compose file

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  api:
    image: fanmixco/example:v0.01
    build:
      context: .
    port:
      - 8080:8080
    network_mode: host
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:9991/MY_DB
```

Have a look on https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#endpoint_mode

Comment: You cannot use the ports in the host configuration.